how to fetch some data from a model in variable?
how to fetch some data from a model in variable without using a list builder?
In this case, my data is being fetched from the API. Now I want my data to go from the model to some of my variables.
e.g.
model
class UserModel {
  String uid;
  String userName;
  String userdesignation;

  UserModel({
    required this.uid,
    required this.userName,
    required this.userdesignation,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
      uid: json["uid"] ?? '',
      userName: json["userName"] ?? '',
    userdesignation: json["userdesignation"] ?? '',
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "uid": uid,
        "userName": userName,
        "userdesignation": userdesignation,
}

UI Part
List<UserModel> userData = <UserModel[];

var email, designation;

Future <void> fecthData() async {

email = userData.first.userName.toString();
designation = userData.first.userdesignation.toString();

print(email);

}


Use index you want to store in email or designation like below.....
email = userData[index].userName.toString();
designation = userData[index].userdesignation.toString();

before call first function check list isEmpty or not if list empty and call first function then throw error ;

You can use a  global variable to store  model data from api call and access values using that variable
UserModel? userData;  // initialize model variable globally 

UserModel _user = UserModel .fromJson(resp);
userData = _user ;  //  in api call assign data to variable like this 
                                           

email = userData.value.userName;  //access like this wherever you want

by following this method  you can fetch data from model and display without listview builder.

ok well, i can try!
